# How to handle SQLite db in case the phone memory is full?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, xamarin.ios

I am using SQLite for storing data for my app to handle it for Offline mode. What happens when the phone memory is full ?
Should we keep any limit to the data saved offline ?
How to handle the above scenarios?

Comment: You mean if the device storage is full?  You should probably display a message to the user telling them to clean up their device's storage.

Comment: @Jason will SQLite throw an error in this case ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure if it can't complete a write it will throw an exception

Comment: @Jason okay will check it.

Comment: `sqlite3_step` returns all kinds of possible results. Most are some sort of error. See the documentation at https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html

Comment: One thing to note is that SQLite uses pages to store the data so often it will use existing pages with free space thus not increasing the file or requiring extra storage. Using [Vacuum](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) as part of the database handling strategy may be beneficial to reducing the potential for such issues. There again it could also be counter-productive freeing space that is then used elsewhere.